# How to learn Bayesian Network's parameters using KL divergence and stochastic optimization?

Tags: bayesian-network

I have a problem to resolve:

A Bayesian Network structure is given to me, with a dataset of values for each variable. I also have a set of queries, like P(A=1 | B=0) or P(L=0, B=1 | C=1).  The goal is to find the parameters of the model.

The first task was to use the frequentist approach. So, for the first query P(A=1 | B=0) we would simply go through the dataset and count how many times (A=1 & B=0) and divide it by how many times (B=0). That was easy.

The second task is to use KL divergence and stochastic optimization to find the parameters. I understand that we want to find Theta = argmin_theta(KL(Pr || Ptheta)). For that, we will go the opposite direction of the gradient of KL, with a step k. I know that to compute the gradient, I can compute the Expectation with respect to Pr of (x - Sigmoid(theta)). x being the value of the current variable. I also have the expression of the expectation.

I get the idea that we want to minimize the gradient of the KL divergence because we want to minimize the difference between our prediction and the truth.

What I don’t understand, is how I’m going to use the structure of the network, the queries, and the dataset to achieve that. I think I’m a bit confused to the end result we really want.

I hope my explanations were not too confusing. If you have any insights I’d take it.

Victor